# wj failed for columns' sum product

Tags: kdb, qpython, rethinkdb-python, qpython3

I have below code and I want to do sumproduct. When I do sum(weight) at `wj`, it works. But if I do sum(weight*price) at `wj`, it failed. How can I do the sumproduct? Thanks!!

```
t:([]sym:3#`ibm;time:10:01:01 10:01:04 10:01:08;price:100 101 105);

price:101 103 103 104 104 107 108 107 108;
weight:98 99 102 103 103 104 106 106 107;
q:([]sym:`ibm; time:10:01:01+til 9; price:price; weight:weight);
f:`sym`time;
w:-2 1+\:t.time;

wj[w;f;t;(q;(sum;`price);(sum;`weight))]; // OK

wj[w;f;t;(q;(sum;`price);(sum;(*;`price;`weight)))]; // failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/wj/#multi-column-arguments) multi-column argumnents can be passed (since 3.6 2018.12.24), but it does not seem that expressions can be passed. Based on that you should be able to rewrite your calculation as a lambda that accepts multiple columns.

```
wj[w;f;t;(q;(sum;`price);({sum x*y};`price;`weight))]
sym time     price weight
-------------------------
ibm 10:01:01 204   20095
ibm 10:01:04 414   42127
ibm 10:01:08 430   45474
```